# 48-bit string of eight 6-bit units: how to get middle 4 bits of each unit quickly

Tags: c, algorithm, assembly, des

I have nearly implemented DES algorithm with C language, and I want to optimize my code. So I used `gprof`.
Here is part of the report:

```
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  us/call  us/call  name    
 51.78      9.32     9.32  8000000     1.17     1.17  sboxes
 34.71     15.57     6.25  8000000     0.78     0.78  extendRight
  9.90     17.35     1.78   500000     3.56    35.96  operation
  2.39     17.78     0.43  8000000     0.05     0.05  xorRightAndKey
```

`gprof` shows that `sboxes` function occupied **51.78%** of the time.

In `sboxes(uchar aucData[6], ...)`, I was given 48 bits, split them into 8 slot, each slot of 6 bits.

for each slot:

1. combine first bit with last bit to get `X`;
2. obtain middle 4 bit to get `Y`;
3. do something with `(X, Y)`;

For example, `011110` is a slot, so `X = 00` and `Y = 1111`.

To implement this, I wrote MACRO to GET/SET bit in memory, here is relative code:

```
#define LOCATE(ptr, index) (((char *)(ptr))[(index) >> 3])

#define GET_BIT(ptr, index) (LOCATE((ptr), (index)) & (((uchar)0x80) >> ((index) % 8)))
```

And here is the code to get `(X, Y)`

```
uchar basePos = 0x00;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    basePos = i * 6; // to locate the slot
    // combine first bit with last bit 
    if (0 != GET_BIT(aucData, basePos)) {
        x |= 0x02;
    }   
    if (0 != GET_BIT(aucData, basePos + 5)) {
        x |= 0x01;
    }   
    // get continuous 4 bits
    for (int j = 1; j <= 4; ++j) {
        if (0 != GET_BIT(aucData, basePos + j)) {
            y |= (0x01 << (4 - j));
        }   
    }   
    // do something with (x, y)
}
```

So my question is, I was given 48 bits, how to get the middle 4 bits as fast as possible?

Comment: If each is 6 bits, can you make a look-up table?

Comment: You can probably write separately optimised routines for a sequence that spans multiple bytes and for a sequence that does not. This would avoid the current bit-by-bit approach.

Comment: C99 or assemble. Because I have to link this code to other languages such as Java and Objective-C .

Comment: Fastest way: lookup table. You can break the lookup table into 3 8-bit lookups (768 entries), and repeat for the first and last 24 bits.

Comment: The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-box) even shows an example of using a lookup table!

Comment: You should read David Feldmeier's paper [A High-Speed Software DES Implementation (1989)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.56.6834).

Comment: You might want to peek at the code of [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without lookup table:

```
typedef unsigned long long u64;

void sboxes(uchar aucData[6])
{
    u64 v = aucData[0] + (((u64)aucData[1]) << 8)
    + (((u64)aucData[2]) << 16)
    + (((u64)aucData[3]) << 24)
    + (((u64)aucData[4]) << 32)
    + (((u64)aucData[5]) << 40);

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
    {
        uchar x = ((v & 1) << 1) | ((v >> 5) & 1);
        uchar y = ((v >> 1) & 0xF);
        // do something with x, y
        printf("x: %hhu, y: %hhu\n", x, y);

        v >>= 6;
    }
}
```

Full disclaimer: I didn't benchmark. But it should be fast. You may be able to do the packing into u64 faster, if it's still too slow.

Comment: First your code does not work, I have tried to fixed it, but in vain. For example, I was given 16 bits `00001111 00001111`, I have to consider byte order.

Comment: How does it fail to work? I tested it before submitting. Unless I misunderstood the question. If a slot has bits ABCDEF, then X = FA, Y = BCDE, correct? Unless you are saying that the contents of the input array are not in order (i.e. the correct order is _not_ aucData[0] -> aucData[1] -> aucData[2] -> ...)

Comment: X = AF, sorry for my expression ability. If we are given `uchar aucData[6] = {0xfc, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55}`, then `v` would be `0x000055443322113fc`, after `v >>= 6`, the right 6 bits of `0xfc` disappeared, but the left 6 bits of `0xfc` is the first slot.